# How to auto-save checkbox states?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cakephp

I used the code of autosave the checkboxes, but while i check the check boxes it is showing that the checkbox is checked and it is saving in the database as well but when i uncheck the checkbox it is unchecked but the data is saving in the database.

So my problem is when i check it will show checked and should save in DataBase and when am unchecked it will uncheck the checkbox and will not save in the database.

I used code in .ctp file

```php
if($applicantform['applicant_application_detail']['applicant_stmnt'] == 'Y') {
    $applicant_stmnt = true;
} else {
    $applicant_stmnt = false;
}
<?php
echo $this->form->input('applicant_stmnt', array(
    "div" => false,
    "type" => "checkbox",
    "value" => "Y",
    'name' -=> 'applicant_application_detail[applicant_stmnt]',
    'checked' => $applicant_stmnt,
    'data-name' => 'applicant_stmnt',
    "label" => "Student shhould submit all certificates"
);
?>
```

and the script for this is

```js
$("checkbox").on('change', function() {
    var name = $(this).data('name');
    var name_val = $(this).val();
    var f_id = $('#f_id').val();
    var applicant_id = <?php echo applicant_id; ?>;
    
    $.get(path){});
});
```

Comment: When posting code, please make sure that it's [**a) valid, and b) working**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (as in it reproduces your problem)! Both your PHP and JS code have syntax errors, your jQuery path doesn't match your form code (there is no `<checkbox>` element), and the callback is incomplete.